# How to disable user input while dealing with buttons in rasa?

Tags: python-3.x, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

I am new to using Rasa and stack overflow as well.
I am creating a restaurant search bot in Rasa but I am stuck with an issue in buttons.

```
utter_ask_budget:
- buttons:
    - payload: cheap
      title: Lesser than Rs. 300
    - payload: medium
      title: Rs. 300 to 700
    - payload: expensive
      title: More than 700
    text: what is your budget?
```

I created this response and it shows buttons when it asks for budget but issue is it also shows a text input field so that user can enter a custom value in that field. I don't want that to happen. I want to restrict the response to buttons only no text field. I checked on Rasa forum but I couldn't understand the answer.

So turned to stack overflow community.

I would appreciate any help with this issue

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess when you refer to 'Text Field' you mean where the user typically types the message.  I don't think you can disable that: the buttons allow to provide predefined options to the user, easy to use but he/she can decide to type a message instead.

If this the case you need to validate the message you receive is one of the expected values.

Comment: It is possible I read on Rasa forum but I couldn't understand how

Comment: Which channel are you using?

Comment: channel as in ? I am new to Rasa so less aware of terms :(

Comment: I mean if you use the chatbot on Telegram, or Facebook, or a web browser. Each client might provide the possibility or not

Answer (score 0):

You can send your own custom elements by using “custom:” key in utter templates.

Here is my example:

```
utter_buy.confirm:
    - text: "Are you sure?"
      buttons:
        - title: "Yes"
          payload: "/affirm"
        - title: "No"
          payload: "/deny"
      custom:
        input_type: "disable"
        back_button: true
        exit_button: false
```

don’t forget to re-enable buttons on next bot message…

Comment: For which frontend this is working, I am using rasa webchat by Botfront, I don't see the desired results.